# Is there any benefit in keeping generated timestamps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm writing my first Ruby on Rails app, and I noticed that generating migrations adds timestamp columns to the table. I have used timestamps before (e.g. when ordering to find the newest record). Are there any reasons to keep these timestamp columns if you have no plan to use them?

Comment: It keep track of your records, facilitate to ordering your data and all. If you don't required those stuff, then there is no need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't plan to use them, there is no benefit. Rails add those for your own sanity and usefulness to be able to see when the records were created and/or updated.

If you want to turn that off, you might want to add this:

```
config.active_record.record_timestamps = false
```

Comment: Thank you, that's all I needed to know :)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. But you severely limit your ability to order and audit your data.